# How can I restore the state of an AdapterViewFlipper in a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a `Fragment` that shows different view by a `AdapterViewFlipper`.
The `AdapterViewFlipper` is being set with `MyCustomAdapter` that contains 'View 1', 'View 2', 'View 3', and 'View 4', and its in a layout resource file that I inflated in my own Fragment "onCreateView()".

The Problem I'm facing is whenever I rotate my device, the current view in the `AdapterViewFlipper` goes back to the first view that was added in `MyCustomAdapter`.

For Example: if the current view in the AdapterViewFlipper is showing 'View 2' and the user rotates the device, it returns back to 'View 1'.
So what I'm trying to do is to restore the current view in the `AdapterViewFlipper` and its state in the Fragment whenever I rotate my device.
Although I found this method that says I should declare the `android:configChanges` attribute at the  element in the AndroidManifest and it worked like a charm but when I was reading about it Android didn't recommend it.
But this works fine in Activity.
So is there a way I can go through this myself?

Comment: How are you retaining your fragment's state?

Comment: I have a Activity named HomeActivity with a Fragment named HomeFragment, the Fragment is shown in the HomeActivity whenever the Activitys onCreate() method gets called, and it was done using the FragmentTransaction.replace(int, Fragment) method, where int is the ViewGroup ID I'm replacing with my Fragment, (at Argument) Fragment is the Fragment (HomeFragment) inflating my own custom views.

Comment: My problem is: when I rotate the device, all the views in the Fragment resets. So where is the right place to save a fragments state? (In the parent Activity lifecycle or in the Fragments lifecycle?).

Answer (score 1):

So the first thing you need to do, is to make sure you are retaining the fragment itself. And not place a new instance every time your activity is re-created.

You can establish that with a simple check in your `onCreate()` method.
You can either check if the `savedInstance` `Bundle` parameter to `onCreate()` is `null`, in that case only you need to replace your fragment OR check if your fragment is already added to your `FragmentManager`.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // This is a brand new activity, and not a re-creation due to config change
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(id, yourFragmentInstnace, stringTag);
}
```

OR

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) == null) {
    // This is a brand new activity, and not a re-creation due to config change
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(id, yourFragmentInstnace, fragmentTag);
}
```

And you also need to call `setRetainInstance(true)` in your fragment's `onCreate()` or something.

That will retain the same instance of your fragment during a configuration change.

This should automatically allow your `AdapterViewFlipper` to maintain its UI state, which is the current item it's showing.

You can find a nice example [here](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html)